# Still logged in after changing password

Tags: bug, android-app, logout

I have Stack Exchange app in my Android phone. Using my computer I changed my Stack Overflow password. After that when I used my SE app in my smartphone my account was still logged in with my old password although I have changed the password. I guess it should logout automatically whenever somebody changes the account password.

Comment: Logging out other devices (read: browsers) is [meta-tag:status-planned], but I'm not sure off the top of my head how that would affect mobile apps (if at all).

Comment: Tip: always have descriptive title, not just "I have a problem".

Comment: I will try to be more descriptive from now on.